# Sorting SitemapNodes based on the count of child elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, sitemap

In an application i am reading from sitemap file adding it on to a `SiteMapNodeCollection` Iterating through it and rendering the results based on some conditions.

But before passing on these `SiteMapNodeCollection` for the manipulation i need to sort the nodes based on the number of childnodes(including if any sub child nodes).I thought of using Extension methods but am confused on using the same,as it is a hierarchial collection.

```
SiteMapDataSourceView siteMapView = (SiteMapDataSourceView)siteMapData.GetView(string.Empty);

//Get the SiteMapNodeCollection from the SiteMapDataSourceView
SiteMapNodeCollection nodes = (SiteMapNodeCollection)siteMapView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

***//Need to sort the nodes based on the number of child nodes it has over here.***

//Recursing through the SiteMapNodeCollection...
foreach (SiteMapNode node in nodes)
{
//rendering based on condition.
}
```

could give me guidance on moving ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a method which calculates a subnodes count for the node specified like this:

```
private static int GetChildNodeCount(SiteMapNode node)
{
    var nodeCount = node.ChildNodes.Count;
    foreach (SiteMapNode subNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        nodeCount += GetChildNodeCount(subNode);
    }

    return nodeCount;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
var orderedNodes = nodes.Cast<SiteMapNode>()
    .OrderBy(n => GetChildNodeCount(n));

foreach (SiteMapNode node in orderedNodes)
{
    //rendering based on condition.
}
```